# Stream never seems to reach end

Tags: c

I have a stream like so:

```
FILE *fp;
byte *buf;
size_t len;
fp = open_memstream(&buf, &len);
```

I write some bytes into it.

Now I want loop from the beginning of the stream to the end. I have a method that that does something like this

```
void method(FILE *fp)
{
   while(!feof(fp)){
     fread(Buffer, sizeof(byte), BUFSIZE, fp);
   }
}
```

But the while loop never stops. I also explicity tried to write EOF char to fp but feof did not work. What's going on here?

Comment: What are you doing inside the `while` loop that will make the stream be at the end?

Comment: I am using fread
fread(Buffer, sizeof(byte), BUFSIZE, fp);

Comment: so, didn't you think of `while (fread(Buffer, sizeof(byte), BUFSIZE, fp) > 0)`? Note, that `EOF` is a marker that will not be set until you try to `fread()` beyond the end of the file, so in the best case you will have one extra iteratin. But you already ignore the return value of `fread()` everyone seems to ignore the return value of functions...

Comment: Very good point but I'm curious why feof is not registering the EOF char that I have explicitly written to stream?

Comment: Because `EOF` is not a `char`. It's `-1` what char is that?

Comment: so what does it mean when I write EOF to a stream? Does it not write anything to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that you are using the wrong function, you can't read from a stream created with `open_memstream()` that's meant for writing only, what you need is

```
FILE *fp = fmemopen(buffer, size, "r");
```

this way you can read from `buffer` as if it was a `FILE *` stream.

Also, `EOF` is not a `char`, not because for example `getchar()` returns `EOF` that means it's a character, it's actually a special value that indicates the `EOF`.

And in fact [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)